# Self-signed certificates with permanent redirects and www subdomain in apache2

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, ssl-certificate, subdomain

On my local Mac machine I have the following apache conf snippet:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/my_example.cert
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/my_example.key
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

When I open `https://example.com` in Chrome or Safari no problem. However, if I open `https://www.example.com` with Chrome I get:

```
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Subject: example.com
Issuer: example.com
```

In Safari I just get a generic "can't connect to the server" message. I forget the command off the top of my head, but you can check the values of the .cert file. For common name it outputs `example.com`. Is that the problem? Does that value need to be a wildcard? And if so, how do you enter a wildcard when prompted making the cert?

Also, what should the permanent redirect value be? Does it matter if it's `https://example.com` or `https://www.example.com`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect from https on one domain to https on the other, you either need a wildcard certificate or two separate certificates.

Regular certificates only match if the hostname is exactly the same.  Wildcard certificates will match the domain without a subdomain or the domain with any subdomain.  Sub-subdomains (like https://sub.sub.example.com) however, will not match in most browsers (the standards were ambiguous about this case until recently).